# Bind UserControl's control binding from MainModule

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have WPF MVVM application. There i have one user control with popup. When i click on one of the user control's button (Parent Bindings) i wish to show popup. (likewise close)

```
Command="{Binding Parent.ShowPopupCommand}"              

<Popup Name="Popup1" IsEnabled="True"              
IsOpen="{Binding DisplayHelper.IsOpenPopup, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
 </Popup>
```

Instead of writing Dependency Property in user control i wrote separate view model with INotifyPropertyChanged interface. On login i am binding popup IsOpen property from Login.cs

```
RelayCommand _showPopupCommand;
RelayCommand _hidePopupCommand;


public ICommand ShowPopupCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_showPopupCommand == null)
                {
                    _showPopupCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.ShowPopup(), null);

                }
                return _showPopupCommand;
            }
        }

        public ICommand HidePopupCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_hidePopupCommand == null)
                {
                    _hidePopupCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.HidePopup(), null);

                }
                return _hidePopupCommand;
            }
        }

        private void HidePopup()
        {
            DisplayHelper ds = new DisplayHelper();
            ds.IsOpenPopup = false;
        }

        private void ShowPopup()
        {
            DisplayHelper ds = new  DisplayHelper();
            ds.IsOpenPopup = true;
        }
```

but popup is not showing on click.

Please help in this

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you create new instances of DisplayHelper each time you run a command, but the View looks for a DisplayHelper property in the ViewModel.

To fix this, I suggest, you set the DisplayHelper as a property in the ViewModel.

I hope it helped, and if you need me to elaborate, feel free to ask. Happy Coding. :)

Comment: wherever (view) i use user control i should use DisplayHelper as a property in its viewmodel or Login view model is enough?

Comment: I don't know the structure of your ViewModel or Login Model, but you can put it in either of them, just use the Binding properly and you are good to go. Try it out, and if you can't make it work, post more code and I'll have a deeper look.